# Is there a way to use a depletion mode MOSFET "inverse"?

Tags: digital-logic, mosfet, switches

I aquired some surplus led strips and I want to make a certain control circuit for it. I took another goal of using only the components I have laying around. I found a nice reclaimed power MOSFET to switch the LEDs in the parts bin. I designed the circuit and went around to test the aforementioned MOSFET if it still works. Turns out it's a depletion mode MOSFET, not a regular one.

Is there any way to use it in "inverse" so I do not have to flip the whole logic(I spent some 5 hours designing it)? I guess I could put an inverter before it, but I thought maybe there's a more clever way.

EDIT: test rig:

[image]

Comment: What is its part number?

Comment: Can tell tomorrow, when I get home again :)

Comment: An inverter requires  1 x jellybean bipolar transistor and 2 resistors. Or 1 x jellybean MOSFET and 1 resistor. Easy to do .

Comment: indeed, I actually employed one of these MOSFET inverters in the circuit anyway(to convert a normally open pushbutton to normally closed), but I need to count these, as other parts use these mosfets as well and I want to be within limits when possible(my goal of not buying any component and using what I have)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a **negative** voltage to turn off a depletion mode MOSFET, they do **not** behave like an enhancement mode MOSFET with an inverter in front, so adding an inverter will not help you.

Are you sure the MOSFET has not been permanently "enhanced" by being fried?

Comment: The test was done on a breadboard, with a led and a resistor between drain and supply voltage. The supply voltage was also connected to the gate with a pushbutton in between. When the pushbutton was in the off state, the led lit up, button pressed, led turned off, thus I concluded it's a depletion mode mosfet. Datasheet did not specify either if I remember correctly. Will verify, when home.

Comment: Maybe the gate is shorted and you're shorting out the supply. ;-)

Comment: Ah might be. I will conduct the experiment once again, once home.

Comment: Edited main post with my test rig, which I used again now with same results. LED normally on, when switch is closed, it goes off. I guess I can assume, that the MOSFET is fried then?

Comment: Fried. It is (or, rather, *was*) a normal high voltage enhancement mode MOSFET, according to the [datasheet](http://semihow.com/product/data/HFS7N80%20datasheet.pdf). By the way, if the MOSFET was good it would typically sit in the previous state for some time until the gate was driven the opposite way. To test it similarly to the way you show, try maybe 10K in series with the gate and a 10K pull down resistor from the switch to minus on the 9V. That way if the gate is shorted it won't short the supply, and the 10K pull down will suck the gate charge out when the switch is open.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I was looking at the datasheet too, but thought I am stupid or something, because it did not act as predicted. I will see what other transistors I have, maybe some power BJTs or lacking of suitables, will just go out of my initial idea of using only things I have and just buy a brand new one:) accepting answer! Also happy holidays!